# ORA-00036: Recursive SQL level error

Tags: oracle

I have created a view using `'emp'` and `'dept'` table.

```
create or replace view view_test (emp_name,dept_name,location) as
select e.emp_name,d.dept_name,d.location from emp e,dept d
where e.DEPT_NO=d.DEPT_NO;
```

And an `'INSTEAD OF' trigger`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_TEST
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON VIEW_TEST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE VIEW_TEST
SET LOCATION=:NEW.LOCATION
WHERE DEPT_NAME=OLD.DEPT_NAME;
END;
/
```

When I am trying to update the value in `VIEW_TEST`, I am getting the below error:

```
update view_test
set location ='ASIA'
WHERE DEPT_NAME='HR';
```

> ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded

Can anyone please help me..

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Your trigger captures updates on `VIEW_TEST` then tries to update `VIEW_TEST`, resulting in an infinite recursion of updates. I suspect you wanted to update `DEPT` rather than `VIEW_TEST`?

Comment: You can't update the view inside the trigger, you have to update the original table, i.e. "DEPT" table. I update posted the answer you can try that, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

An `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` is helpful when you know a particular logic for how  to handle a `DML` operation on a `VIEW`. Generally, if a view contains multiple joins on tables and we would want to ensure how Oracle needs to handle such inserts/updates on the underlying tables of the view, it is recommended to use such a Trigger.

You are committing a big mistake by trying to update the same view inside the `Trigger`, which, as already told by Ben in the comments, *leads to infinite recursion of updates.*

I think what you were actually trying to do was to update the `dept` table.So, you could re-write your `Trigger` to look something like this.

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER trig_test
  INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON view_test
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE dept
    SET    location  = :NEW.location -- include other columns
    WHERE  dept_name = :OLD.dept_name;
END;
/
```

You may also add additional updates to other columns of underlying tables.
Then, an update statement like yours will work as expected.

```
update view_test set location ='ASIA' WHERE DEPT_NAME='HR';
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct trigger code, that will solve your problem, try it now.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_TEST
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON VIEW_TEST
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE dept
SET LOCATION=:NEW.LOCATION
WHERE DEPT_NO = (select dept_no
                      from dept 
                     where DEPT_NAME=:OLD.DEPT_NAME
                       and rownum <=1);
END;
/
```